How to solve ROS2 Humble Error no -6
When I'm programming a ros2 SLAM Project, This Project.
I'm using Humble Hawksbill ROS2
The error is coming from the line ros2 launch turtlebot3_bringup robot.launch.py
It's showing error no -6, I am purely in simulation, i.e. I'm using  VirtualBox and not using any board. The error is This and it's trying to open the serial port which I don't have it on my Virtual desktop.


Please ask at the ROS forums. People there would be more knowledgeable about this

Okay , thank you
